# Sending secure mail in go lang using gmail server

Tags: go, gmail

I need to send emails in go lang program using gmail.
There are several examples I found that require Google Account Security Settings to be changed.
Could someone point me to an example where mail is sent without changing google security?

I tried the following:

```
servername := "smtp.gmail.com:465"
host := "smtp.gmail.com"
auth := smtp.PlainAuth("","john@gmail.com", "johnpassword", "smtp.gmail.com")

// TLS config
tlsconfig := &tls.Config {
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    ServerName: host,
}

conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", servername, tlsconfig)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}

c, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}

// Auth
if err = c.Auth(auth); err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}

The Auth call fails and shows the following error:


535 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
```

Comment: 1. check if the user has 2fa enabled. if so you need a key instead of password.  2. try this https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: I will be using google mail api instead.  But having issues there as well ::   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64267579/googleapi-error-404-requested-entity-was-not-found-while-sending-email