# googleapi: Error 400: Recipient address required, invalidArgument

Tags: go, gmail-api

I am running following script to send email message. The From and To addresses are replaced by sender and receiver.

```
func SendMail() {

b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("credentials.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
}

config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, gmail.MailGoogleComScope)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", 
err)
}
client := getClient(config)

srv, err := gmail.New(client)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Gmail client: %v", err)
}

user := "me"
mailtext := `From: sender@gmail.com
To: receiver@gmail.com
Subject: Saying Hello
Date: Thu, 8 Oct 2020 09:55:06 -0600
Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>

This is a message just to say hello.
So, "Hello".
`
raw := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(mailtext))

var message gmail.Message
message.Id = "Msg 2"
message.LabelIds = []string{"SENT"}
message.Raw = raw

doFunc := srv.Users.Messages.Send(user, &message)
m, err := doFunc.Do()
if err != nil {
    println(err.Error())
    println("Message not sent")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("%+v", m)
}
```

The script reports the following error:

```
googleapi: Error 400: Recipient address required, invalidArgument
```

Environment:  macOS Catalina 10.15.7  go1.15.2 darwin/amd64

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your script, I cannot understand about your goal. You want to send the existing draft message? Or you want to send the existing draft message by updating the draft message? Or you want to create a draft message and send it? Or you want to just send an email?

Comment: I just want to compose new mail and send it.  I have modified code and removed draft message and just creating a message and trying to send it.Now I see recipient address required error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and updating the script, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Have you tried sending the message using the Gmail API explorer? It should show the same error, perhaps a bit more detailed.

Comment: I have credentials.json and access.json on my system. I can create a post request in go and use the REST API you suggested but I don't know how I could use the json files for security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to send an email using googleapis for golang.
- You have already been able to get and put emails using Gmail API.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that `mailtext` is required to be modified. In this case, the line break and spaces are important.
- Although `raw` is created, that is not put to the request body.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
    mailtext := `
    From: sender@gmail.com
    To: receiver@gmail.com
    Subject: Saying Hello
    Date: Thu, 8 Oct 2020 09:55:06 -0600
    Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>

    This is a message just to say hello.
    So, "Hello".
    `
    raw :=  base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(mailtext))

     // create gmail.Message

     var message gmail.Message
     message.Id = "Msg 1"
     message.LabelIds = []string{"SENT"}
```

To:

```
    user := "me"
    // Modified
    mailtext := `From: sender@gmail.com
To: receiver@gmail.com
Subject: Saying Hello
Date: Thu, 8 Oct 2020 09:55:06 -0600
Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>

This is a message just to say hello.
So, "Hello".`
    raw := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(mailtext))

    // create gmail.Message

    var message gmail.Message
    message.Id = "Msg 1"
    message.LabelIds = []string{"SENT"}
    message.Raw = raw  // Added
```

- I think that in this case, `Date:` and `Message-ID:` might be replaced with new values.
- Or, please modify `mailtext` as follows.

  ```
    mailtext := "From: sender@gmail.com\nTo: receiver@gmail.com\nSubject: Saying Hello\nDate: Thu, 8 Oct 2020 09:55:06 -0600\nMessage-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>\n\nThis is a message just to say hello.\nSo, \"Hello\"."
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: users.messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)

Comment: Made the changes suggested in the code. But I still get the same error: googleapi: Error 400: Recipient address required, invalidArgument.

Comment: @Tusshu Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide your whole script? Because in my environment, I can confirm that the modified script worked. I apologize for this. Can you provide your whole script?

Comment: I have replaced the original script above with the copy of script I am running on my machine. The only change is the sender and the receiver email address. Thanks for helping out!   Also replaced the title of the bug by the actual error I am receiving.

Comment: @Tusshu Thank you for adding more information. Unfortunately, when I tested your script by replacing the email address, I can confirm that no error occurs and an email can be sent. So I cannot replicate your issue of `googleapi: Error 400: Recipient address required, invalidArgument`. I apologize for this. So for example, when `mailtext` is `mailtext := "From: sender@gmail.com\nTo: receiver@gmail.com\nSubject: Saying Hello\nDate: Thu, 8 Oct 2020 09:55:06 -0600\nMessage-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>\n\nThis is a message just to say hello.\nSo, \"Hello\"."`, what result will you get?

Comment: I DON'T BELIEVE THIS BUT IT WORKS!!!. Thank you very much for helping me out from beginning of my struggle, including previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248806). Back tic character (`) is routinely used to write multi line string so I never suspected that to be a problem. Well, now I know! Thanks again for your patience and resolving the issue. I do't know how to mark this question as "answered".

Comment: The problem was  that there were tabs at the beginning of last 4 lines of mailtext in my code. I missed this point while looking at the modified script you suggested.

Comment: @Tusshu Thank you for replying.